# Using a microchip Pic32 and LAN8740 series PHY, How so I read the values in the PHY status registers?

Tags: c, lan, microchip, pic32

Using the Harmony 3 framework, I can get information on the MAC layer using:
`TCPIP_STACK_NetMACRegisterStatisticsGet()`

I am having trouble with the PHY not starting up though and want to read the 'control and status' registers listed in the datasheet.  I can't work out how to get to them though.  Access seems to be multiple layers down in the API and I can't find a way to access the low level read functions during normal operation.

I have tried accessing the PHY pointers but I an not sure this is the correct mechanism, and I have been unable to use them in any useful way to access the register data

```
// Access the MAC pointer which is otherwise well hidden in the stack code
`pMacD = DRV_ETHMAC_QUARCH_GET_pMAC (0);
// Access the PHY pointers
pPhyBase =  pMacD->mData.macConfig.pPhyBase;
hPhyClient = pMacD->mData.hPhyClient;`
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.